# Trouble with flutter radio button

Tags: dart, flutter

I just want to have normal radio buttons where only one button in the group can be selected. According to tutorials online we need to set the groupvalue variable to the value in the setState method in onChanged. If i do this i can select all buttons and i dont want this to happen. I want only one button to be a selected at a time(from that group). if there is anything wrong with my code or any other way to do it let me know.

option is the string parameter for title optionvalue is the value for that option.

```
class Option extends StatefulWidget {
  final String option;
  final int optionvalue;

  Option(this.option, this.optionvalue);

  _OptionState createState() => _OptionState();
}

class _OptionState extends State<Option> {
  int groupvalue;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Container(
        child: RadioListTile(
          title: Text(
            widget.option,
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
          ),
          activeColor: Colors.black,
          value: widget.optionvalue,
          groupValue: groupvalue,
          onChanged: (int a) {
            print(a);
            setState(() {
              groupvalue = a;
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 34):

Try this code

```
int _groupValue = -1;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      _myRadioButton(
        title: "Checkbox 0",
        value: 0,
        onChanged: (newValue) => setState(() => _groupValue = newValue),
      ),
      _myRadioButton(
        title: "Checkbox 1",
        value: 1,
        onChanged: (newValue) => setState(() => _groupValue = newValue),
      ),
    ],
  );
}

Widget _myRadioButton({String title, int value, Function onChanged}) {
  return RadioListTile(
    value: value,
    groupValue: _groupValue,
    onChanged: onChanged,
    title: Text(title),
  );
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the code, but im using a constructor to instantiate the buttons(i have a lot of radio buttons). I cant include all radio buttons in the build method . If you could alter my code what changes would you make(if its possible).Thanks for replying.

Comment: @Suhas G I updated the code to match your needs, check this one out. It has got a function which builds `RadioListTile`

Comment: thanks for sharing this code:)

Comment: Actually I choose RadioListTile with groupvalue so It can be modified on text. Check that example of that. http://techandroidhub.com/creating-a-radio-widget-in-flutter/

Comment: @SawanModi What's your point? I am already using `RadioListTile`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this for horizontal radio button list:

```
int _groupValue = -1;

Container(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text('Gender', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18)),
                Container(
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Expanded(
                            flex: 1,
                            child: RadioListTile(
                              value: 0,
                              groupValue: _groupValue,
                              title: Text("Male"),
                              onChanged: (newValue) =>
                                  setState(() => _groupValue = newValue),
                              activeColor: Colors.red,
                              selected: false,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            flex: 1,
                            child: RadioListTile(
                              value: 1,
                              groupValue: _groupValue,
                              title: Text("Female"),
                              onChanged: (newValue) =>
                                  setState(() => _groupValue = newValue),
                              activeColor: Colors.red,
                              selected: false,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: Better to answer the question in the simplest way possible.  Horizontal list and other layout properties only distract from the answer.