# how to make my radio button to be only one of them can be selected

Tags: flutter, dart

I want only one radio button to be a selected at a time(from that group). But all of my radio button can be selected. What should I do to fix this this problem?

Here is my main code

```
    body: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: quizData.length,
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                Results results = quizData[index];
                List<String> allAnswer = results.incorrectAnswer;
                allAnswer.add(results.correctAnswer);

                return ListTile(
                    title: Text("${index + 1}. " + results.question,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 15.0,
                        )),
                    subtitle: Container(
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: allAnswer.map((choice) {
                          return AnswerChoice(
                              allAnswer,
                              allAnswer.indexOf(choice),
                              choice,
                              allAnswer.indexOf(choice));
                        }).toList(),
                      ),
                    ));
              }),
        ),
      ],
    ));
```

And this is the code that going to create the radio button

```
class AnswerChoice extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<String> results;
  final int index;
  final String choice;
  final int abjadIndex;
  AnswerChoice(this.results, this.index, this.choice, this.abjadIndex);

  @override
  _AnswerChoiceState createState() =>  _AnswerChoiceState(this.choice, this.abjadIndex);
}

class _AnswerChoiceState extends State<AnswerChoice> {
  int selectedRadio = -1;
  final int abjadIndex;
  List abjadList = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
  Color colorPressed() {
    return Colors.green;
  }

  final String choice;
  _AnswerChoiceState(this.choice, this.abjadIndex);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RadioListTile(
      value: widget.index,
      groupValue: selectedRadio,
      onChanged: (val) {
        setState(() {
          selectedRadio = val;
          print("jawaban: " + choice);
          print(widget.index);
          print(selectedRadio);
        });
      },
      title: Text(
        "${abjadList[abjadIndex]}. " + choice,
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I've tried the similar problem on this question [Trouble with flutter radio button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55217448/trouble-with-flutter-radio-button), but nothing is changed

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the location of the Variable `selectedRadio`.

You have created one `selectedRadio` for each radio. So in your `onChanged`, you only change the `selectedRadio` from the clicked radio.

Use one variable outside the `AnswerChoice` to the `groupValue` and when you change it, it will be replicated with all Radios of the group.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:ui';

class AnswerChoice extends StatefulWidget {
  //final List<String> results; Unused
  final int index;
  final String choice;
  final int groupValue;
  final ValueChanged<int> onChanged;


  //final int abjadIndex; equal Index
  AnswerChoice(this.index, this.choice, this.groupValue, this.onChanged);

  @override
  _AnswerChoiceState createState() =>  _AnswerChoiceState(this.index, this.choice, this.groupValue);
}

class _AnswerChoiceState extends State<AnswerChoice> {
  int selectedRadio = -1;
  final int index;
  final int groupValue;
  List abjadList = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
  Color colorPressed() {
    return Colors.green;
  }

  final String choice;
  _AnswerChoiceState(this.index, this.choice, this.groupValue);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RadioListTile(
      value: widget.index,
      groupValue: groupValue,
      onChanged: widget.onChanged,
      title: Text(
        "${abjadList[index]}. " + choice,
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Create a function like that in your main:

```
     void changeOption(int val) {
        setState(() {
          _groupValue = val;
        });
      }
```

And in your main you will must have a variable `_groupValue` and your map will be something like:

```
    allAnswer.map((choice) {
      return AnswerChoice(
      allAnswer.indexOf(choice),
      choice,
      _groupValue,
      changeOption);
    }).toList()
```

Comment: i'm sorry but can you explain me more what should I change in the code? i don't really get it, i'm new on flutter. Btw thanks for answering my question

Comment: @MuhammadDhai'ul, I think it's it.

Comment: the code doesn't work and the apps becomes like [this](https://ibb.co/W0BZmPw) every time I clicked the button, here is [my full code](https://github.com/telurkucing/dart/blob/master/quiz_1.dart) , am I missing something?

Comment: The error is on `build` method from `_AnswerChoiceState` the `groupValue: selectedRadio,` should be `groupValue: groupValue,`. Sorry about that, I corrected it in my answer.

Comment: You apear to be having a problem when you iterate your data from JSON. The last item is been generated multiple times. But I can't see the reason in the provided code.