# Flutter: Select single item in using Radio

Tags: flutter, radio-button

I have a widget who need to select a single item using Radio as dynamically. I already created that widget like below:

```
int number;
return Container(
        child: Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Radio(
              value: index,
              groupValue: number,
              activeColor: Color(0xFFE91E63),
              onChanged: (int val) {
                setState(() {
                  number = val;
                  print('Show the Resumes $number');
                });
              },
            ),
            Text(
              'Show',
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
```

I looping the above widget inside a `ListView.builder`. And the `index` in the `value` is from `index` from `itemBuilder` on `ListView.builder`. And when I run the code, it looks like [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1l89122G5APInKNcmP0aY38TNLfsQ01wZ/view?usp=sharing).

So how to make my Radio is only select a single item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can write like this, declare `value` and `groupValue` outside the loop (`builder` in `ListView`). And create `value`, `groupValue`, and `onChanged` in the constructor. And the result like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VX4N3.jpg).

```dart
...

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  List<int> _numbers = List<int>.generate(5, (index) => index);
  int _groupNumber;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return HomeContent(
            value: _numbers[index],
            groupValue: _groupNumber,
            onChanged: (int value) {
              setState(() {
                _groupNumber = value;
              });
            },
          );
        },
        itemCount: _numbers.length,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HomeContent extends StatelessWidget {
  final int value;
  final int groupValue;
  final ValueChanged<int> onChanged;

  const HomeContent({
    Key key,
    this.value,
    this.groupValue,
    this.onChanged,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RadioListTile<int>(
      value: this.value,
      groupValue: this.groupValue,
      onChanged: this.onChanged,
      title: Text('Value $value On Group $groupValue'),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change 'groupValue: number' to

```
final var _groupValue = -1;
return Container(
    ...
    groupValue: _groupValue,
    ...
);
```

and show [Trouble with flutter radio button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55217448/trouble-with-flutter-radio-button)